# Flutter: PlatformException "Cancelled by a second request" in MethodChannelFilePicker

Tags: flutter

I am encountering an error in my Flutter application when using the FilePicker. The error message I receive is:

```
flutter: [MethodChannelFilePicker] Platform exception: PlatformException(multiple_request, Cancelled by a second request, null, null)
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(multiple_request, Cancelled by a second request, null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:496:35)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FilePickerIO._getPath (package:file_picker/src/file_picker_io.dart:92:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _MyHomePageState._addRecording (package:ear_boost/main.dart:256:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

It seems to be related to file picking or accessing the file system using the FilePickerIO class. The error is triggered by a cancellation caused by a second request, as indicated by the "multiple_request" code in the PlatformException.

I am using the latest version of the FilePicker plugin and Flutter framework.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any insights on how to resolve this error? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!